# Fluid tooltip w/ absolute positioning

Tags: html, css, tooltip, css-position, overlay

I am having difficulties with an absolute-positioned, right-side tooltip getting cropped while open and the tooltip is near the right-side of the viewport.

If the viewport is small, the tooltip will extend past the viewport. I am looking for the tooltip to extend to the edge of the screen (fluid).

**Is there are a CSS solution to this?**

Tooltips from Predix or other design systems will have smart tooltips that just move the tooltip below/above the icon but I would like to keep the same user expectation that the tooltip will appear to the right.

```css
body {
  background-color: #999;
}
button {
  background-color:transparent;
  bordeR:none;
}

.container {
  width:100%;
  padding-top:50px;
  padding-left:280px;
}

.tooltip-container {
  position: relative;
}

.tooltip-text {
    display:block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    max-width: 850px;
/*  Hiding the min-width will cause the tooltip to word-break at every word   */
    min-width: 300px;
    padding: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: 0 6px 12px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    top: -36px;
    left: 160%;
    
}
.tooltip-text:before {
     width: 1rem;
    height: 1rem;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    content: "";
    background-color: inherit;
    left: 1.5rem;
    bottom: -.5rem;
    margin-left: -.5rem;
    top: 32px;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <span class="tooltip-container">
    <button class="tooltip-button">
      <i class="fas fa-lg fa-info-circle"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="tooltip-text">
      This is a Long tooltip that I want to be fluid and extend to the edge of the screen but not get cropped when the screen shrinks. Currently sitting at a width of 300px.
    </div>
  </span>
```

Other solutions for this:

*Smart tooltip* that will move the tooltip above/below the icon

*JS viewport detection* that will calculate the icon position and viewport width and calculate the min-width value of the tooltip and assign it thus.

?